# Inferring transition rates from continuous markov chain question

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> A house has 2 rooms of similar sizes with identical air conditioners
>   equipped with thermostats which turn on and off as needed to maintain
>   the temperature in each room to a desired level of 22 degrees. Suppose that a
>   thermostat remains on or off for exponential amounts of time with
>   means $1/\mu$ and $1/\lambda$, respectively, independently of other thermostats. Consider the Markov process $\{X(t), t \ge 0\}$ whose state space is the number of active air conditioners. Write down the matrix of transition rates.

I'm not sure how to exactly approach this type of question. My working is as follows but if someone could clarify my confusion that would be good.

Working:

So clearly there are 3 states, 0 for no air conditioners are on, 1 for one air conditioner is on (active), and 2 for two air conditioners are on (active). Now to work out $q_{01}$, i.e., the transition rate from state 0 to 1, assume currently no air conditioners are on. Consider the two independent poisson processes both with parameter $\lambda$, where the interarrival time is the duration of "off", then merging these two processes gives a poisson process with parameter $2\lambda$, so the transition rate from state 0 to state 1 is $2\lambda$.

Now what about the transition rate from state 0 to 2? I am told that it's 0, but why? Isn't it possible for both air conditioners to both go from "off" to "on"? What is the argument that $q_{02} = 0$?

Comment: That the number of active air conditioners is a Markov process would require an argument. What is the source of the exercise?

Comment: It is a tutorial homework question, the solutions say $q_{02} = 0$, but I do not know why that is the case. The question is exactly as stated.

Comment: The fact that one never jumps drectly from 0 to 2 (nor from 2 to 0) is clear. Let me suggest to ask your TA why they think this process is Markov (when $\lambda\ne\mu$).

Comment: My question is why can you not go from 0 to 2? Isn't it possible to have both air conditioners that are both "off", then both go "on" at the same time? In this case, you will you go from no active air conditioners, to two active air conditioners?

Comment: Ah, but this is direct: the times when each air conditioner switches are independent and their distributions have no atom hence, almost surely, they never switch simultaneously.

Comment: Let me reiterate: to assert that X is Markov needs justification and if X is not Markov, the tools one uses in Markovian settings disappear.

Comment: Ok let's assume that it is Markov for now. Regarding the independence, that I do get, but just because they're independent, how does that mean there's no chance for them to switch on/off at exactly the same time? I'm just not quite getting why it's impossible for them to turn on/off at the same time.

Comment: Please read: "they are independent" `and their distributions have no atom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two independent Poisson processes, let $(T_n)$ and $(S_n)$ denote the times when they increase. Then the probability that they both increase at a common time is bounded by
$$
\sum_{n,m}P(T_n=S_m).
$$
Here is a technical result which may help:

> **Lemma:** Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and that $Y$ has no atom, that is, $P(Y=y)=0$ for every $y$. Then, $P(X=Y)=0$.

Applying this to each $(T_n,S_m)$ shows that the probability that two independent Poisson processes both increase at a common time is zero.

To prove the lemma, note that, by definition of the distribution $P_{(X,Y)}$ of $(X,Y)$, then by independence of $(X,Y)$, and finally by Fubini, one has
$$
P(X=Y)=\iint\mathbf 1_{x=y}\,\mathrm dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=\int\left(\int\mathbf 1_{x=y}\,\mathrm dP_Y(y)\right)\,\mathrm dP_X(x),
$$
that is,
$$
P(X=Y)=\int P(Y=x)\mathrm dP_X(x),
$$
and, since $P(Y=x)=0$ for every $x$, we are done.